Movie ID - going over Niagara Falls in a barrel
Can you identify this movie.
I saw it many years ago, I think late seventies, but it could be older.
Plot, as far as I can recall, was a teenage boy/ young man on a journey, in 19th or very early 20th Century America or Canada.  He has several adventures along the way, each essentially a separate story.
One segment has him becoming an assistant to a magician.  The magician intends to perform a "Going over Niagara Falls in a barrel" trick. It was intended to be a conjuring trick - he would be seen stepping into the barrel, but slip out through a false bottom. However, something goes wrong and he actually does go over the falls. He survives, but is badly bruised.  Then the young man heads off to his next adventure.
I don't recall any other segments.

Could it be one of the movies listed here?

Doesn't look like any of them.

Identified  on another forum.
TV show Hunter's Gold, episodes 4-5.
It wasn't Niagara Falls, it was rapids in New Zealand. No wonder a keyword search failed to find it.
